# how to access localhost using ip of pc?

Tags: apache, ip, webserver

I am trying to run my local host app using my system ip but its not working.

http://localhost/bootstrap/bs1.html  - working

http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/bootstrap/bs1.html -not working

using ipconfig command I got the ipv4 .

how to make it?

Comment: What server software and OS are you using?

Comment: xampp and windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using IPConfig, I assume you are using Windows as well.

Open notepad as administrator, navigate to `Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and open `hosts` file (Windows 10).

Uncomment or add a new line with following entry:

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

Then flush your DNS cache in your terminal with command:

`ipconfig /flushdns`

You might experience browser caching at this point, close and reopen browser if needed.

This is for localhost only, so host machine and guest machines (if any).

If you want to give an access to your server externally, like for anyone over the internet, this is much more complicated tasks and would require port forwarding.

But there is simpler solution and workaround for doing it and I recommend using [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which is super simple CLI tool that will do work for you.
It's a secure solution as you are not exposing anything on your computer directly but instead it uses a secure tunnel to provide your localhost on `*.ngrok.com/*` link.

Comment: how can i open this page in my mobile browser ??

Comment: In this case you are using internal ip that's visible only to your computer - 127.0.0.1. The IP you have received from `ipconfig` config is an ip that your Internet Service Provider shares with you and that's ip address used outside of your local network.

Comment: If you want to see your project on external devices, I recommend using proxy such as browser-sync and point it to your website on localhost. Using browsersync CLI will serve small proxy server and return you an external IP address that can be used on your mobile phone to access it. Browsersync - https://www.browsersync.io/ and my favourite way of using browsersync is via Gulp - https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/

Comment: but how ?can you give me some more idea or links ?

Comment: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line CLI instructions and installation instructions here: https://www.browsersync.io/docs#installation

Comment: Just make sure your mobile and pc are in the same network (same wi-fi network for example). Otherwise you will need to use external tunnels like Ngrok.